# I want to pipe grep output to sed for input

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I'm trying to pipe the output of grep to sed so it will only edit specific files. I don't want sed to edit something without changing it. (Changing the modified date.)

I'm searching with grep and writing with sed. That's it

The thing I am trying to change is a dash, not the normal type, a special type. "-" is normal. "–" isn't normal

---

The code I currently have:

```
sed -i 's/– foobar/- foobar/g' * ; perl-rename 's/– foobar/- foobar/' *'– foobar'*
```

---

Sorry about the trouble, I'm inexperienced.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Take the [tour] and read [ask]. You should edit your question to include more detail about your use case, example inputs, desired outputs and what you've tried. As it stands, there isn't really a question here.

Comment: There isn't? I need to connect grep with sed, isn't that a question? Sorry.

Comment: No, `I need to connect grep with sed` is a statement, not a question. You haven't told us what, if anything, is wrong with the code you have or asked any questions about whatever is wrong it (assuming something is) that you need help with. As mentioned before, see [ask].

Comment: If your question is "how to connect grep with sed?", the answer will likely be "use a pipe." Your post implies there is more to the problem than that. You're getting guesses as answers for a reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for helping, I'm sorry about not being fast in responding

After a bit of fiddling with the command, I got it:

```
grep -l 'old' * | xargs -d '\n' sed -i 's/old/new/'
```

This should only touch files that contain `old` and leave all other files.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure about what you want to achieve? Let me explain you:

```
grep "string_in_file" <filelist> | sed <sed_script>
```

This is first showing the "string_in_file", preceeded by the filename.
If you launch a `sed` on this, then it will just show you the result of that `sed`-script on screen, but it will not change the files itself. In order to do this, you need the following:

```
grep -l "string_in_file" <filelist> | sed <sed_script_on_file>
```

The `grep -l` shows you some filenames, and the new sed_script_on_file needs to be a script, reading the file, and altering it.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're trying to do if your file names don't contain newlines:

```
grep -l -- 'old' * | xargs sed -i 's/old/new/'
```